# Can't change width of textarea

Tags: html, css, forms, textarea, width

I can't change the width of textarea using html rows and cols nor can I change it with css width. I've changed the height with html.

How would I change the width?

```css
form,
label {
  position: relative;
  width: 310px;
  margin-left: 65px;
}

input,
textarea {
  border-radius: 4px;
  line-height: 30px;
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  height: 35px;
}

label,
input,
textarea {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: -300px;
}

form {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 580px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-area"><label class="l-message">Message * <textarea name="message" type="textarea" class="message" style="height: 105px;" required></textarea></label></div>
```

Comment: Um, did you try `width: something;`?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways you can change the width. You can do it inline or within the CSS. The CSS is the recommended way to do it. Please see the snippet below

```css
    form, label {
    position: relative;
    width: 310px;
    margin-left: 65px;
    }

    input, textarea {
    border-radius: 4px;
    line-height: 30px;
    flex: 0 0 200px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    height: 35px;
    width: 100%; /* or whatever width you want to set */
    }
    .form-area {
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    padding: 0px 0px 40px;
    margin: 30px 265px 0px;
    border: 1px solid GREY;
    border-radius: 6px;
    width: 710px;
    height: 360px;
    }

label, input, textarea {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: -300px;
}
form {
margin-top: 100px;
margin-left: 580px;
display: block;
margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-area"><label class="l-message">Message * <textarea name="message" type="textarea" class="message" style="height: 105px;" required></textarea></label></div>
```